# Fancybox is undefined

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I am trying to create my own next and previous arrows in a fancybox 2 popup.
It works fine to include them but when I click them I get that $.fancybox is undefined.
I am opening a page using ajax.

This is my fancybox init code:

```
$(".popup").fancybox ({

maxWidth    : 1200,
maxHeight   : 550,
width       : '90%',
height      : '90%',
autoSize    : false,
openEffect  : 'none',
closeEffect : 'none',
nextEffect: 'none',
prevEffect: 'none',
arrows: false,
padding: 0,
scrolling: 'no',
afterShow: function (e) {

var toolbar = "<div id='next'>Next</div><div id='prev'>Prev</div>";

$(".fancybox-inner").append(toolbar);

}

});
```

This is my next and previous code:

```
$("#next").live ("click", function() {

$.fancybox.next();

});

$("#prev").live ("click", function() {

$.fancybox.prev();

});
```

Both of these code samples resizes in a javascript file called popup.js that I have
included on the page where I call the popup window.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would rather do

```
var toolbar = "<div id='next'><a href="javascript:$.fancybox.next();">Next</a></div><div id='prev'><a href="javascript:$.fancybox.prev();">Prev</a></div>";
```

and forget about your `.live()` scripts.

BTW, as of jQuery 1.7, the `.live()` method is deprecated. Use `.on()` instead. For older versions of jQuery the use of `.delegate()` is preferred over `.live()`.